# executenonquery requires an open and available connection. the connection's current state is connecting

Tags: c#

I am using c# application for receiving strings from tcp client. And storing in Database(Sql server 2005).Application working fine but some time it is  giving error

"executenonquery requires an open and available connection. The connection's current state is connecting "

it is coming every day again restart the application it is working fine after some time the error will come

when i get this error my has lost it is not storing in database my code behind

```
 try
 {
      if (Latitude != 0 && Longitude != 0)
      {                               
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert_Mapapp", con);
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Latitude", Latitude));
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Longitude ", Longitude));
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Speed", Speed));
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Battery_ADC ", Battery_ADC));
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sDateTime ", sDateTime));
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Main_Backup_Battery ", Main_Backup_Battery));
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Pulse_Counter ", Pulse_Counter));
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Number_of_Satellites ", Number_of_Satellites));
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IgnitionStatus ", IgnitionStatus));
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Condition_Inputs ", Condition_Inputs));
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FuelADC ", FuelADC));
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UID ", UnitID));
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Device_IP", remoteIP));
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Device_Port", remotePort));
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@String_Count", UIDCounter));
           cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Stored", Stored));
           // cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nofrec", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
           if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
               cmd.Connection.Open();
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
         AddTextToListBox(ex.Message);
          AddTextToListBox(tmp);        

       }
       finally
       {
           if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
           con.Close();
       }
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Not that this answers the question, but top lesson. Don't have an empty catch block.

Comment: Remove the empty catch, also use the `using`-statement which closes the connection. Note that there are other states than `ConnectionState.Open` and `ConnectionState.Closed`.

Comment: For which reason you need to check connection state? Isn't open and disposed within your method with another using statement? No reason to check, just call Open()...

Comment: Show the declaration of `con`, is it static?

Answer (score 4):

I think you should change your if statement to:

```
if(cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
```

Comment: The best way is using a `using`-statement and always `cmd.Connection.Open();`.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
 {
   if (Latitude != 0 && Longitude != 0)
   {                               

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert_Mapapp", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Latitude", Latitude));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Longitude ", Longitude));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Speed", Speed));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Battery_ADC ", Battery_ADC));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sDateTime ", sDateTime));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Main_Backup_Battery ", Main_Backup_Battery));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Pulse_Counter ", Pulse_Counter));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Number_of_Satellites ", Number_of_Satellites));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IgnitionStatus ", IgnitionStatus));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Condition_Inputs ", Condition_Inputs));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FuelADC ", FuelADC));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UID ", UnitID));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Device_IP", remoteIP));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Device_Port", remotePort));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@String_Count", UIDCounter));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Stored", Stored));
        // cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nofrec", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        if (cmd.Connection != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
            }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


  }
 catch (Exception ex)
  {
      throw;
  }
finally
     {
       if (cmd.Connection.ToString() != String.Empty && cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                CONN.Close();
     }
```